# Prometheus last value sticks forever for gauges and counters

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I have a metric set up to gauge some queue size, as following :

```
metrics.addGaugeMeasure({
        name: queueSize,
        description: 'Queue size',
        labels: ['pipelineName', 'jobId', 'source', 'target'],
    });
```

The metric is set per unique "jobId", and once the assosicated "job" in the micro-service is finished, i do not set any more values to the pairing pipelineName - jobId - source - target..

Upon inspection of the /metrics endpoint, i can see the above pairing of pipelineName-jobId, holding the last set value.

This causes a big confusion for what the system state is.
What am i missing / doing wrong?
What might be the solution ?

Thanks.

edit:
This is an example of data in prom-ui,
[image]

Around the the middle of 22-23 mark on the x-axis, i stopped writing data to the said metric, and the data stays in said state..

Answer (score 0):

The numbers exposed by `/metrics` (in your case) endpoint are just values to be stored in the time series storage. Let's say you have a gauge that reports a queue size -- a TS storage stores the value of data with a timestamp:

```
time queue
12:00 1
12:01 7
12:02 3
12:03 3
12:04 3
...
```

Next step is making a queries (with *a time range* of interest) to transform the raw values into a meaningful metric. F.e. for a gauge it might be a 1-hour [**delta()**](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta):

`delta(my_queue_size{jobId="foo"}[1h])`

Prometheus does have a rich set of [aggregations](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) and [functions](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/) to fit your needs.

Comment: The issue is i am not sending the data explicitly, but the graph seems to be a straight line without any data loss or stop.

I am trying to understand what part of my code or setup is causing this behavour.

I am monitoring data that can be 1 minute, of 12 days straight, i have no way to know in advanced, so my graph is so called not limited to a time of interest

Comment: the graph is a "straight line" after job is finished because after finishing the job the last raw value is being kept. To make the graph more meaningful you might want to apply the function, such as "delta" -- in that case after job is finished it would show `0` (last_val - last-val=0)

Comment: Is there a way to make the values non existant?
The correct way to represent the queue size for example, and many other metrics in my case, would be non-existant, in the context of the key pair.

Comment: you could report the metric value as `0`, that would mean "empty queue", after the job is completed